# Is $\vert 2^m - 11^n \vert$ ever equal to $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Calculate
$$ \min_{m, n \in \Bbb N_+} \vert 2^m - 11^n \vert .$$
A computer has a hard time figuring this one out.
I'm going to sleep on it.

I'm curious about the differences 
$$ \vert 2^m - p^n \vert $$ in general when $p$ is an odd prime.

Definitely seems false, but not sure why.

Comment: $2^2-3^1 = 1$, $|2^2-5^1|=1$ and $2^3-7^1 = 1$. And the minimum cannot be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show that indeed $3$ is the minimum value.

If $2^m-11^n=2$, we have an obvious contradiction mod $2$.

If $2^m-11^n=1$, then if $m=1$, $n=0$, a contradiction.

So, assume $m \geq 2$, so $2^m \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Then from $2^m-11^n=1$ it follows that $11^n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, and so $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Then, $2^m=11^n+1=(11+1)(11^{n-1}-11^{n-2}+\cdots-11+1)=12k$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

So, $12 \mid 2^m$, a contradiction.

We are done.

Comment: Thanks!  Small typo in the second last line.

Answer (score 6):

By [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) this is never equal to $1$, it is clearly an odd number, and $\vert 2^3-11^1\vert =3$.

Comment: Small issue when applying the theorem because of the absolute value signs, but thanks for the reference.

Comment: Yes that's just a matter of changing the order. And you're welcome. If you're curious, I can recommend the [book](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781848001848) by Rene Schoof in the Universitext series.

Comment: Wouldn't $|2^3 - 7^1| = 1$ be a counterexample?

Comment: @OpenSeason To what exactly? Your original question is about the minimum of $|2^m-11^n|$. Mihăilescu's theorem holds for powers greater than $1$, and I implicitly assumed it was clear that no power of $2$ differs from $11^1$ by $1$.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry about that.