# $x, y \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}.$ Find the smallest value of $P = |36^x - 5^y|.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $x, y \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}.$ Find the smallest value of $P = |36^x - 5^y|.$

Here's my attempt using calculus:

Fix $x. P'(y) = 0 \iff y = y_{0} = x\log_5 36 \approx 2.23x.$

Also, $P'(y) > 0$ for $y > y_{0}$ and $P'(y) < 0$ for $y < y_{0}.$ Since $y \in \mathbb{N},$ $P$ reaches its smallest value when $y = 2x$ or $y = 3x$ - that is, when $P = P_1 = |36^x - 5^{2x}|$ or $P = P_2 = |36^x - 5^{3x}|.$

Both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are increasing monotone over $[1, \infty],$ so $P_1 \geq |36 - 25| = 11$ and $P_2 \geq |36 - 125| = 89.$ Thus, $P_{min} = 11.$

---

I suspect there is a shorter way using number theory, but I have not been able to find it. For context, I'm not well-versed in number theory other than having some basic knowledge of divisibility and congruences, but I'm eager to pick up new bits of it as I go. I hope to hear your methods.

Thank you!

---

**EDIT**: I just realized that my calculus solution is not correct. $y$ could be a fraction of $x$ that gives a natural number, not neccesarily a multiple of $x.$ I think I should go to bed now, but I'll think about it in the morning and update the original post if I have anything new!

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1913906p13112628), or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893650/minimal-value-of-a-diophantine-expression?noredirect=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320678/is-vert-2m-11n-vert-ever-equal-to-1?noredirect=1), and many more.

Comment: You can't do this with calculus; but even if you could, you'd have to round $y$, not $y/x$, to an integer. Hint: which primes can't divide $P$? What are the smallest values this doesn't preclude? Which are achievable? (You need to rule out $P=1,\,P=7$ with modulo arguments.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much! I'm checking them out, but it's too late on my side and I'm so sleepy now so I'm likely to get back to you in the morning!

Comment: @J.G Thank you for your suggestions! I also just realized that problem with my solution. It's a bit late on my side and my brain is a little foggy so I'll think about your hints more carefully in the morning and get back to you afterwards. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at $|36^x-5^y|\pmod{180}$. I chose $180$ because $36\cdot 5=180$, so it seemed like an interesting modulus to try.

Notice that $36^2\equiv 36\pmod{180}$, so by induction, we can show $36^x\equiv 36\pmod{180}$ for all $x\geq 1$. Ergo, the expression is equivalent to one of the following:
$$
(36-5^y)\pmod{180}\ \ \ \ \text{ or }\ \ \ \ (5^y-36)\pmod{180}
$$
depending on whether $36^x < 5^y$ or $36^x > 5^y$.

Now, if you look at $5^y\pmod{180}$ for small values of $y$, you will notice that $5^7\equiv 5\pmod{180}$. With this, we can prove by induction that $5^{6+y}\equiv 5^y\pmod{180}$ for all $y\geq 1$, meaning that the expression $5^y\pmod{180}$ is periodic with period $6$, so if we want to find all values of the expressions $(36-5^y)\pmod{180}$ and $(5^y-36)\pmod{180}$, it suffices to look at just $y=1,2,3,4,5,6$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
y & (36-5^y)\pmod{180} & (5^y-36)\pmod{180} \\ \hline 
1 & 31 & 149 \\
2 & 11 & 169 \\
3 & 91 & 89 \\
4 & 131 & 49 \\
5 & 151 & 29 \\
6 & 71 & 109
\end{array}
$$
As we can see, the minimum value in this table is $11$, so $|36^x-5^y|\pmod{180}$ is always at least $11$. Since $|36^x-5^y|$ is a non-negative integer, this means $|36^x-5^y|$ is always at least $11$. Finally, know that $|36^x-5^y|=11$ when $x=1,y=2$, so this suffices to show that $11$ is the minimum possible value of $|36^x-5^y|$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$|36^x - 5^y|=|6^{2x}-5^y|=|(5+1)^{2x}-5^y|=\left|5^{2x}-5^y+\sum^{k=2x}_{k=1}\binom{2x}{k}5^{2x-k}\right|$$ It is clear that $(x,y)=(1,2)$ gives the minimum $11$.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Nobie Mushtak's solution...

We have
$$P\equiv\pm 1\pmod2$$
$$P\equiv\pm 1\pmod3$$
$$P\equiv\pm 1\pmod5$$
The smallest such $P$ is $11$, which occurs when $x=1$, $y=2.$

$P=1$ is not possible due to [Mihailescu's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "a deep theorem"?